# How do I check whether a reference is const?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, constants, type-traits

I was writing a test for my iterator types and wanted to check that the reference returned by de-referencing iterators provided by `begin()` and `cbegin()` are non-const and const respectively.

I tried doing something similar to the following : -

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{0};

    std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(*vec.begin())>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(*vec.cbegin())>::value << std::endl;
}
```

But this prints `0` for both cases.

Is there a way to check if a reference is const?

I can use C++11/14/17 features.

Comment: Reference can never be const-qualified. Only the type to which a reference is referred can be const-qualified. `std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the reference to get the referenced type to inspect its constness. A reference itself is never const - even though references to const may colloquially be called const references:

```
std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*it)>>
```

Comment: It calls for the definition of `template<class T> constexpr bool is_const_ref_v = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;`.

Answer (score 5):

`*it` will be a reference rather than the referenced type (`int&` or `const int&` rather than `int` or `const int` in your case). So, you need to remove the reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{0};

    std::cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*vec.begin())>::type>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*vec.cbegin())>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This produces:

```
0
1
```

Note: The above works uses C++11. @eerorika's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53444770/1593077) is more terse, but requires C++17.

Answer (score 3):

`is_const` always returns `false` for references. Instead, do:

```
std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*v.begin() )>> // false
std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*v.cbegin())>> // true
```

Comment: Is `is_const_v` preferable over `is_const` ?

Comment: @Flau it's just shorter. Drawback is that it requires C++17.

Comment: @Flau `_v` variants are a shorthand to avoid writing `::value`; the same way `_t` ones avoid `::type`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the notes on document here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const

- Notes

> If T is a reference type then is_const::value is always false. The
>   proper way to check a potentially-reference type for const-ness is to
>   remove the reference: is_const::type>.

```
for(auto it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*it)>::type>::value << std::endl;
}

for(auto it=vec.cbegin(); it!=vec.cend(); ++it) {
    std::cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*it)>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @YSC lol, I edited my sentence, but I think instead of giving an answer, I want to give an advice for future question